# What SharePoint SKUs are on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, site-policies, 7-essential-questions

I've noticed confusion around tagging the various SharePoint products which led me to think about what's on topic here. For example, just listing recent versions:

- SharePoint Foundation 2010
- SharePoint Server Standard 2010
- SharePoint Server Enterprise 2010
- Search Server Express 2010
- Search Server 2010
- Search Server Express 2008
- Search Server 2008
- Windows SharePoint Services 3.0
- SharePoint Server Standard 2007
- SharePoint Server Enterprise 2007

Are all of these on topic for our site or are there grey areas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of those products could be on topic as long as the question is about the SharePoint part.

You should use a version tag *ONLY* when your question is version specific. For those questions, use the major version tag, for example: [2007](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2007) [2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2010).

See also:

1. [Should we tag questions with a SharePoint version?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/should-we-tag-questions-with-a-sharepoint-version)
2. [Version tags considered harmful](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/version-tags-considered-harmful)
3. [Numeric version tags considered … OK](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok) (follow up to #2)