# What's going to happen to questions about Office 365?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should we allow questions about products that don't belong to a SharePoint SKU?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/when-should-we-allow-questions-about-products-that-dont-belong-to-a-sharepoint-s)

Since there are different products involved (Exchange, SharePoint, Lync, Office Clients) I am wondering where questions about Office 365 should be asked?

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Online would definately be **on**-topic. Other products like Lync and Exchange I would deem off-topic. There are grey areas though, since parts of the federation model etc are clearly on-topic for SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

If it's [about the SharePoint platform](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/when-should-we-allow-questions-about-products-that-dont-belong-to-a-sharepoint-s/130#130) then it's on topic.

As @Anders says, there will be grey areas. We'll need to deal with them on a case-by-case basis.