# Time to expand the scope to include other/all Office 365 services?

Tags: discussion, site-policies

So, there have been an increasing number of questions around the MS Graph API, MS Teams, OneDrive, etc. that are not specifically centered around SharePoint. In most cases, it appears that other users have answered those questions anyway, despite technically not being included on the [official on-topic help page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  Of note, "SharePoint Online" is not listed on that page, nor is any O365 service, although InfoPath and Yammer are specifically mentioned as being "on-topic".  Although it appears that questions about [Exchange/Outlook](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook), [Excel](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/excel), and [Azure](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/azure) Functions are hit or miss whether the community answers or closes as off-topic.

I realize that this is almost duplicate of [this question](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147/whats-going-to-happen-to-questions-about-office-365), and [this one](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/when-should-we-allow-questions-about-products-that-dont-belong-to-a-sharepoint), both asked nearly **9 years ago**, but clearly the capabilities, customizations, integrations, and API's of Office 365 have evolved considerably in the decade since.  If it is more appropriate to re-open one of those older questions to add more discussion, we can certainly close this one.

I think it is time we consider at least updating the on-topic page to explicitly draw the lines about which portions of Office 365 and SharePoint Online are considered on-topic for this community, and potentially consider opening it to allow questions pertaining to all of Office 365, since there are no other dedicated stackexchange communities to those services.

Comment: Thanks for your initiative, you are right, the on-topic page is not up to date, and it's partially updated now, It would be also great to provide us with any additional details that you find it should be added! and we will reflect it!
Thanks again for your effort to improve the community ♥

Comment: I would recommend at least adding a bullet point to the top section worded something like " - Office 365 services that are dependent upon SharePoint, such as Groups, Teams, and OneDrive".

Comment: This would be a natural evolvement as SharePoint is the backbone of many services in Office 365. The days where we could say that we only worked with SharePoint are long gone...