# Can we post Commerce Server questions here?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should we allow questions about products that don't belong to a SharePoint SKU?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/when-should-we-allow-questions-about-products-that-dont-belong-to-a-sharepoint-s)

Can we post Commerce Server questions here, or should it go into StackOverflow?

Answer (score 2):

If the question is related to operating CS with SharePoint (i.e. it is about SharePoint), I would say yes.

If it's about CS functionality specifically, no.