# Move Office Fabric Tags and Q's to StackExchange

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, questions

There's a couple of tags and questions that are around the Office UI Fabric and its components.

- [fabric](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fabric)
- [office-ui-fabric-react](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-ui-fabric-react)
- [office-ui](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-ui)

Should these be moved to StackOverflow? The project is outside of the core SharePoint product. Fabric is used for both SharePoint and Office client add-ins so questions around this might not even relate to SharePoint at all. The answer to [what is and is not acceptable](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/when-should-we-allow-questions-about-products-that-dont-belong-to-a-sharepoint/130#130) from 2011 walks a fine line for product extensions.