# Are we allowed to ask questions based partially or entirely on third party applications that integrate with SharePoint?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, allowed-questions

I couldn't find a definitive question/answer/kb on this. If there is one (fairly up-to-date), please kindly point me to the right direction and close/delete the post.

I understand that generally speaking, it appears that all **questions related to third party applications** are closed as off topic. Is this true? And if so, shouldn't we give the chance of someone knowledgeable and willing to help, to do just that?

Sometimes, questions are more conceptual rather than technical, and I feel that, if we don't allow any questions blindly, we are losing value.

Obviously I don't want to enable a place for doing support for these tools on behalf of their owners.

e.g.

K2 Blackpearl, AvePoint DocAve, Metalogix, Harmon.ie, Nintex, etc.

Appreciate any clarification on this.

[Similar discussion](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/when-should-we-allow-questions-about-products-that-dont-belong-to-a-sharepoint) (back in 2011).

Answer (score 1):

As you already pointed out, 3rd party applications are off topic for this site. These applications already have their own support channels, and you are supposed to use them. This is especially true for payed for applications like the ones you mention in your question.

Free Open Source 3rd party applications also falls into the same category, but some of them (SPFx and others) are valid since they are supported by the vendor.