# Tag synonym instead of blocking it: sharepoint2010 --> 2010

Tags: feature-request

You decided that [Numeric version tags considered ... OK](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok) and the `2010` tag exists.

SharePoint has big differences (Feature/Development wise) between the 2007 & 2010 version and one **should** differentiate via tag IMHO (same goes for a newer version once it comes out).

Right now the "sharepoint2010" and "sharepoint-2010" (same goes for 2007) is blocked. Why not **create some synonyms** for those instead of blocking them as `2010` is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

The question you refer to was a follow up to a [previous question](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/version-tags-considered-harmful) that contained the following rather pertinent section:

> Version tags are a crutch. Because these tags dominate the site, and
>   contain the name, they are the first thing users will turn to when
>   tagging their questions. This means users will fail to tag questions
>   with any other meaningful tags, since "I already tagged my question
>   with sharepoint-2003!" This isn't hypothetical. We've seen this happen
>   time and time again. Version tags are a mindless replacement for
>   thinking about what your question is about. "Oh, this question is
>   about sharepoint-2010. Done."

A very large percentage of questioners will start adding a tag by typing "sha", then stop and rethink if there are no available tags.

Comment: Good comment on this and I agree that users sometimes stop to add tags once they have the general one. Yet I hate having to ask the questioneer "what version of SP is this?".