# Again about version specific tag

Tags: discussion, tagging, review-page

Just saw this proposed edit.

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8685

The edit only retagged the question to introduce the 2010 tag. Now, feel free to correct me but the question doesn't seem version specific, so based on the original meta discussion and Jeff guidance here [Numeric version tags considered ... OK](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/numeric-version-tags-considered-ok) the version tag is **less-than-desired**.

Yet is seems that the edit has been approved. Why? I am missing something - have the tagging policy changed or can I roll back the edit and assume that the approvers were wrong (Bad approvers, bad. Not reading meta are they)?

PS: if someone can invoke the mighty Jeff to leave an answer here, I would really appreciate it (it like a new badge - You have an answer from Jeff / Skeet). Even better would be if Jeff removed that tag and replaced it with the "Do not tag me 2010" one. ^_^

Comment: Accepted twice actually.

Comment: @rjcup3 - yes, I was referring to that. "Approved" as per approved edit, so at least two people should have agreed with the edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree - the version tag should not be used unless the question is about that specific version. I have edited the question to get rid of the 2010 tag again and also to remove the version reference in the question title. I could find nothing in the question that suggested that it was in any way version specific, and as far as I know calculated columns have not changed.

This whole version tagging is going to be even more problematic as Microsoft move to the more frequent release cadence.

Comment: ops, forgot to accept.

Comment: Hopefully as MS moves to more frequent releases they will stop bothering with version numbers

Comment: @RyanErickson and in the meantime, here we go again. [How add item name with URL in EditForm?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30518/how-add-item-name-with-url-in-editform). Another change that add a version tag to a question that doesn't need it?

Comment: I am rejecting edits that add the 2010 tag (unless the question were to be specific to SP2010 - and this hasn't happened yet).

Comment: Thanks. One edit attempt gone. Now I can edit the question and actually improve it (for example by adding the img IN the question...). I would have done it before by counter-editing it... but I wanted the "do not add 2010" message to be clear.