# Like hats? You can have one by celebrating the holiday season with StackExhange!

Tags: discussion, hats, winter-bash

> Last year, on our Gaming site, we hosted an event called [Hat Dash](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/),
>   where users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain
>   tasks (analogous to badges). Certain actions would trigger the user
>   receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear".
>
> For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora
>   with pen) to the editor. I've included some examples from last year in
>   the attachments.

Some examples:

[image: Raven pirate] [image: users with hats]

**This year.. we have the option of participating as well!**

This event will run from 19 December 2012 to 4 January 2013. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterba.sh. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally  anti-hat will have an "I hate hats" option available, just as we had on Gaming last year.

The only visual change to the site itself will be the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.

**What do you guys think? Should we participate?**

Comment: Hats! Hats are the best! :D

Comment: How long would the hats be visible on the site? Only for that date range or permanently?

Comment: The ones on Gaming where visible only for the date range. That said, IMHO it would be cool if the behaviour was extended - keep the hats, but wear them only in special periods (sort of an advanced badge).

Comment: Sounds like fun!

Comment: @Kit-Menke Aarthi just sent a reminder if we want to participate, could you mail her and say we opt-in?

Comment: @AndersRask Yep will do!

Comment: @KitMenke ... Remember to post on the 21... don't want to lose that....

Comment: Oh geez.. now people are voting on bad questions just to get hats.

Answer (score 5):

The real question should be: "which hats do you want to see?"...

Trad: just go for it and start thinking about something SharePoint-themed ^_^'.

Some suggestion (updated as new hats come to mind):

**Clippy Hat**: 10 answers that where flagged as "this post does not really answer the question" (OOKK, just joking here).

**Voodoo Mask** (has some Office simbols hanging): something similar to the necromancer badge - have to think about it.

**Say SharePoint and Enter** (A Moria-like gate with the SharePoint logo): ten answers about claims, form auth and so on.

**Kitchen Timer** (A tomato-shaped kitchen timer): 10 answers on questions tagged as "timer job".

**Living Fossil** ([Nautilus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus_pompilius) shaped): Asked a question / posted an answer to a question tagged 2003.

**Santa Little Helper** (Elf-like hat and ears): one flag was deemed usefull.

**Santa Claus** (need to say?): manually awarded a bounty on the 25 of december.

**Robot Santa** (based on the Futurama char.): deleted a bounty-pending question. OR voted to delete/close X bad question/answer.

**I love Version Tags** (Jeff avatar hairs - Coding Horror logo): removed at last 20 useless version tags. See [here](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/version-tags-considered-harmful).

**Dromedary** (a dromedary head): answered 10 questions tagged CAML (for the ones that don't get the joke... [here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/15055544-fda0-42db-a603-6dc32ed26fde))

**Legendary Super User** (Yellow, sparking, pointy hairs): reputation level is over nine thousand...

**Evil Mastermind** (Mandark styled): have asked a question titled "How to corrupt content database?". Why should it use that graphic? Search the question and you will understand :P (hope @Shoban doesn't get mad for this ^_^ - always loved that question, and actually tried to find some creative answer)

**We are the robots** (Cardboard Robot styled, with Conchords logo): triggered the Captcha check (and let's hope that the check is the same as Stack...).

---

***April fool special guests:***

**Weaponizzed Pony** (Unicorn Head): entered [the](http://snaptortoise.com/konami-js/) [code](https://code.google.com/p/konami-js/) while on the meta site. Can add some [cornify](http://www.cornify.com/) bonus for added effect.

**[Title] Princess** (Pink unicorn head with crown, wings and glittering effect): secret hat - requirement unknown. Must perform some specific actions while wearing the Weaponizzed Pony hat. Note that the title is random and changes beetween words like "Cute", "Glittering", "Nice" and so on...

Comment: Haha! The Clippy hat would be awesome. :)

Comment: Yes, but would anyone post 10 out-of-context answers just for the joy of it? (And would you really want to fix them?)

Comment: I'm all about the Dromedary hat lol.

Comment: OVER NINE THOUSAND!

Answer (score 0):

One of the moderators needs to respond by 28th November if we are going to do the Hat Dash. The default is to opt out.

My reading of this thread is that there isn't a great deal of enthusiasm and maybe it's not for us.

Let the mods know if you want the Hat Dash.

Comment: I am starting to think that is the idea of the prizes that make people opt out of this. With the gamer Hat Dash you could win a console/some game if I don't recall wrong. Here some rumors says that you will win a Clippy peluche or a office logo t-shirt.... no wonder people are scared....

Comment: I feel like we might as well stir things up a little and try it out. :)

Comment: @KitMenke, seeing the "great traffic" that meta usually gets, I belive that many of the user didn't even READ this post... so go figure. I belive that the decision is your. Or you can reverse the pool "all the evil, black hearted people that DON'T like hats (and unicorns, a thing that alone should be sufficient to issue a ban) post now or suffer in silence for about three weeks"

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Agreed. I don't think anyone actually reads meta except the mods and a few people bored at work.

Comment: Time Up. Game Over.

Comment: I think Kit already signed us up.

Comment: Ya, just noticed (evil evil evil Kit that forgot to add a @SPArchaeologist in his comment, forcing me to actually re-read the thread ^_^). Returning to the "create hat list" mode then.

Comment: @KitMenke - any news?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist All quiet so far. I will ask tomorrow.

Comment: @KitMenke, Thanks - good to know. BTW, they need more ideas?

Comment: @SPArchaeologist I think they probably already good to go but I can ask that too.

Comment: Hats are up. Clippy hat missing. Hulk angry. Hulk smash.

Answer (score 0):

The hat dash is a great idea, I rarely get time to come on meta, (I SHOULD MORE) SPDoctor can announce it at SPS12 at the end of his talk :P

****Volunteers him****