# Do we want hats?

Tags: discussion, hats, winter-bash

Last year SP.SE participated in Winter Bash, which lets our users earn and wear hats on their user profile image. You earn hats through participation in asking questions, answering questions, getting up-votes, voting, commenting and sharing to mention a few things. Exactly the same things you’re doing here to earn reputation and badges. But there is a twist, you don’t know what will earn hats. Suddenly, it just appears in a hat-gallery where you can pick the hat of the day. It’s all up to you, hat or no hat. You can chose not to wear any of earned hats. This event is a way of celebrating the many amazing people who make this site awesome.

So, we’re announcing **Winter Bash 2013**!

## Winter Bash Leaderboard

[image: Winter Bash Leaderboard]

## Winter Bash Hats Collection (2012)

A few of the available hats

[image: Winter Bash Hats Collection (2012)]

## Winter Bash Hat Example (2012)

[image: Winter Bash Hat Example (2012)]

## Details

This event will run from 16 December 2013 to 3 January 2014. Users will be able to see their entire hat collection on http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.

But we need to make a decision no later than *Saturday November 30* to participate or not. Simply put;

**Do we want hats?**

## Submitted

It's clear that we want hats, so we have submitted the form to participate in **Winter Bash 2013**.

Comment: Thanks for the URL edit :)

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller You're Welcome :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Obviously, ye have my vote.
.
..
...  and remember that this year we need the "Twilight Sparkle" hat. No winter bash must ever forget the unicorn.

Prototype:
[image]

And - with the help of a random user -

[image]

Perfect - just perfect.

EDIT: HERE!! IT EXIST!

[image]

[still preferring my version...]

EDIT 2: and now somebody claims that this

[image]

was found in some hat sprite sheet...

EDIT 3: 
Ok <strike>officially horned</strike>.
No, don't like how that sound. Let's just say I am a member of the club.

Comment: I'll do my best, but I haven't yet reviled the [Secret of the Unicorn](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161331)

Comment: @BennySkogberg, do you know if the old hat images are still lingering somewhere? If we can have some spec about the required dimension of the images, we could start a "do it yourself" hats proposal post.

Comment: They are stored somewhere, but I don't know if they are publicly available. This [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161622) shows some of the old hats. I'm guessing that there will be new inventions on hats for Winter Bash 2013.

Comment: @BennySkogberg - see the edit. You guys have no excuse now :P

Comment: @BennySkogberg - (also, if you want, remove the second picture. I have used your gravatar only because it was more fitting than mine ^_^)

Comment: Lovely! I'm already in the competition :-)

Comment: @BennySkogberg - How many cookies/unicorn dollars does the above hat cost?

Comment: I bet somewhere around 1000 unidollars would make the trick. Have you asked the unicorn admin master yet?

Comment: @BennySkogberg - ok, so I assume I must ask [him](http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclocks-a-unicorn) ^_^

Comment: @BennySkogberg ...... Can you please explain me [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/a4SzT.png)? seems to come from the hat sprite sheet.

Answer (score 6):

Hats sounds like an awesome way to light up the dark winter!

Answer (score 4):

I'll be the first to put in my vote for participating in the Winter Bash. We can make it an [annual tradition](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/722/like-hats-you-can-have-one-by-celebrating-the-holiday-season-with-stackexhange)!

Answer (score 4):

“All those poor elves I haven’t set free yet, having to stay over during Christmas because there aren’t enough hats!” ~~ J.K. Rowling, Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix.

Saying yes to hats.

Comment: Thanks for that quote! Should be posted on meta.SO!

Answer (score 4):

It's that time of year... Who don't want silly hats ;)

Answer (score 3):

Hats would be a nice twist. You have my vote.

Answer (score 3):

Of course! Why would we *not* want hats?

Answer (score 2):

I vote for hats, if anyone here doesn't want one they don't have to wear it!

Answer (score 2):

I too vote for hats. It is a nice idea!

Answer (score 2):

Definitely I earned quite a few last year and I want more this year!

Comment: We have submitted to opt in, and we'll get confirmation in a few hours :-)

Answer (score 1):

The hats are a good idea, definitely makes it interesting.
There needs to be a "Many Hats" hat where an individual who wears many hats and has many skills/responsibilities can earn. Just a thought for fun...