# SharePoint 2013 Tag Addition

Tags: discussion

I have seen lot of post related to SharePoint 2013, many new members asking question from SP2013. Experts please create a tag with "SharePoint 2013", it'll helpful to lot of us.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone with [more than 300 rep](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) can create a new tag.

If we create a new tag it should

- Be just "2013"
- Only be used for questions that apply ONLY to SharePoint 2013

Read more here: [Should we tag questions with a SharePoint version?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19/should-we-tag-questions-with-a-sharepoint-version)

Answer (score 1):

There is already such a tag. It is called [2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2013).